# What’s the current density on infinite plate?

Tags: electromagnetism

The current density equation states that $J = I/A$.

But I got a question that asking the current density over an infinite plate.
Say the current $I_0$ flows into the infinite plate that extent infinitely on $z$ direction from $x = 0$ to $d$, What's the current density on the plate? The plate in unspecified on $y$.

I have asked a professor regarding this, and the answer is $J = I$. I have trouble to understand why infinite count as 1 in this case. Could anyone sent some help?

Thanks in advance.

edit:

Here is the question, question (a).
[image]

Comment: Related: [Surface current density confusion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/442179/surface-current-density-confusion)

Comment: *I have asked a professor regarding this, and the answer is J = I.* Don’t ask that professor any more questions about EM.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. .I still don`t get the answer. How can I write the current density?

Comment: It seems to me that it’s zero times a delta function. The situation you have described is sufficiently strange than I am skeptical it is really what the problem asked. Can you please edit your question to quote the problem exactly as it is stated?

Comment: I have added the original question. I think those problems are pretty straightforward except (a). Maybe I have a misunderstanding here.

Comment: I find the whole thing confusing. I don’t know what “the structure is *part* of one that is infinite in extent” in the $y$-direction is supposed to mean. I think you are supposed to assume that *this* part has finite extent along $y$.

Answer (score 0):

The question is given in a rather vague language.
The interpretation that the question is demanding is probably the following:

Instead of thinking about I as the total current that is spreading in the infinite area , you could imagine I being supplied to each unit strip where the strips are taken perpendicular to the $x-z$ plane.That is to mean that the source is providing I to all such strips extending in the $y$ direction and hence *the net current through the whole sheet is infinite while current density is I itself.*

Comment: If that`s the case, then (b),(c) and(d) would become infinite.

Comment: Yes. You are right , I didn't even look at the other sub-parts. You might have to consider what G.Smith has said. Maybe the question is requiring to neglect the infinite extension.