# Integral to obtain the current $I$ from the surface current density $\mathbf{K}$, Griffiths' Intro to Electrodynamics

Tags: electromagnetism

I am reading the 4th Edition of Griffiths' "Introduction to Electrodynamics".

It is not clear to me how to obtain the current $I$ from the *surface current density* $\mathbf{K}$.

Griffiths presents us the **surface current density** by considering "a ribbon of infinitesimal width ${\rm d}l_{\perp}$, running parallel to the flow", and defining

$$\mathbf{K} = \frac{{\rm d}\mathbf{I}}{{\rm d}l_{\perp}}$$

as the *current per unit width*, or - in one of the older versions - "the current per unit width-perpendicular-to-flow" (see the screenshot from an older version from [this old post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/442179/surface-current-density-confusion)).

That is: let us slice the plane in the direction perpendicular to the flow (${\rm d}l_{\perp}$) and then we will sum (integrate) together all the current infinitesimal $d\mathbf{I}= \mathbf{K} {\rm d}l_{\perp}$ when the moment comes.

[image]

Same goes for the **volume current density** - I am introducing it because it's the only one for which an expression to obtain the current $I$ is given. Let us consider "a tube of infinitesimal cross section ${\rm d}a_{\perp}$ running parallel to the flow". The **volume current density** is defined as

$$\mathbf{J} = \frac{{\rm d}\mathbf{I}}{{\rm d}a_{\perp}}$$

That is: let us slice the cylinder in this rods of squared base ${\rm d}a_{\perp}$ and then, when the moment comes we will sum (integrate) together all the current infinitesimal $d\mathbf{I}= \mathbf{J} {\rm d}a_{\perp}$.

[image]

Now, as I said, an expression with a surface integral is given to obtain the current $I$ flowing through a surface $\mathcal{S}$ from the volume current density

$$I = \int_{\mathcal{S}} J {\rm d}a_{\perp} = \int_{\mathcal{S}} \mathbf{J} \cdot {\rm d}\mathbf{a}$$

where "the dot product serves neatly to pick out the appropriate component of ${\rm d}\mathbf{a}$", that is the dot product selects the infinitesimal areas whose normal is parallel to the flow, i.e. the infinitesimal areas orthogonal to the flow.

But then it is not explained **how to obtain the current $I$ from the surface current density $\mathbf{K}$**! For consistency with the volume case, where we used a surface integral, one would be tempted to use a line integral in this case

$$ I = \int_{l_{\perp}} \mathbf{K} \cdot {\rm d}\mathbf{l}.$$

Where I am integrating on the side of the plane orthogonal to the flow, $l_{\perp}$.
But I believe this would be $0$, as the scalar product will pick-up the component of $\mathbf{K}$ parallel to ${\rm d}\mathbf{l}$, which is null in this case, since we selected - to begin with - an infinitesimal of length perpendicular to the flow ${\rm d}l_{\perp}$.

So **what is a formal, elegant, expression to obtain $I$ from $\mathbf{K}$ with a line integral and why is not provided?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also cannot find a sufficient explanation for this. The way I have been getting around this is to use the magnitude of equation 5.22 in 4th Edition of Griffiths' "Introduction to Electrodynamics".

Equation 5.22:

$$\mathbf{K} = \frac{{\rm d}\mathbf{I}}{{\rm d}l_{\perp}}$$

Now, the magnitude of $\mathbf{K}$ is:

$$\mathbf{|K|}=\frac{{\rm |d}\mathbf{I|}}{{\rm d}l_{\perp}}$$

or

$$\mathit{K}=\frac{{d}\mathit{I}}{{\rm d}l_{\perp}}$$

Now,

$$\mathit{K}{{\rm d}l_{\perp}} = {dI}$$

so that,

$$I = \int K {\rm d}l_{\perp} $$

By taking the magnitude, you essentially "remove" the dot product from the process because, in this situation, $\mathit{K}$ is perpendicular the $\mathit{l}$ which as you stated, would result in a dot product of zero.

This seems to be what Griffiths does in Example 5.8 considering the amperian loop he has drawn is perpendicular to $\mathit{K}$.

I still think my interpretation of this is incorrect somehow, but this way works for solving examples and problems involving surface currents in this textbook. If someone else has a better explanation please let us know!

Answer (score 4):

In finding the flux of current through a 2D surface using the 3D current density, the area vector is defined as being perpendicular to the surface.  To use a dot product to find the current crossing a line (or curve), on a 2D surface you would need to define the the dL vector as being perpendicular to the corresponding line segment.  (This is not a standard line integral.)

Answer (score 0):

I actually found that if you recall Griffith's definition of K vector:
K = dI / dl
where K and dI are vectors, and dl is the differential length that's perpendicular to the flow,

dI  = kdl

I = Int ( K dl)

there would be no dot product because K is a vector and dl is a scalar, hence our problem is resolved.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/413645)