# CGS Units of surface current density

Tags: superconductivity, units

The exercise is to calculate the surface current density of Pb at $T = 4.2K$. The critical temperature $T_c$ and the critical field at zero temperature is given: $T_c = 7.2K$ and $H_c(0) = 803Oe$. I use $H_c(T) = H_c(0) [1-(T/T_c)^2]$ to calculate $H_c(4.2K)$.

For the surface current density I use $j_{surf} = \frac{\mathrm{c}}{4\pi}H_c(4.2K)$.
I get $j_{surf} = 1\cdot 10^{12}\frac{\mathrm{A}}{\mathrm{s}}$.
The official solution is $j = 422 \frac{\mathrm{A}}{\mathrm{cm}}$.

This is just an example of my problems. When I calculate it using the formulas in the textbook, the units wont add up and my result just does not make any sense.
I just do not understand what I am doing wrong. Maybe someone can explain what went wrong in this example.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_units#Electromagnetic_unit_names.    
I think the units in the solutions are correct
$[j] = [c][H] = cm\,s^{-1} \cdot Oe =cm\,s^{-1} \cdot cm^{-1/2}\,g^{-1/2}\,s^{-1}=cm^{1/2}\,g^{-1/2}\,s^{-2}$
I now divide and multiply by $cm$ to get the current in $Fr/s$. I get
$cm^{3/2}\,g^{-1/2}\,s^{-2}/cm = Fr/s/cm$. And then I guess $Fr/s$ are changed with $A$, though those are SI units, right?

Comment: Also it is a surface current density, so when multiplied by a small width $dx$ in $cm$ it should give you ampere, so $A/cm$ is definitely the correct unit, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/630948/integral-to-obtain-the-current-i-from-the-surface-current-density-mathbfk

Comment: I missed looking up the basis units. I still do not get the same resulting value which is confusing to me but I take it. At least the units do make sense now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Okay, it also figured out how to get to SI units if wanted. Now, I also get the solution as in the textbook. :)